Error restoring Savepoint in AWS KDA with Flink 1.15
I have a Flink 1.15 application running on AWS KDA (Managed Apache FLink). The application is being subjected to Snapshot (savepoint) on update. I got this exception (at the bottom of the message) I think because I moved a wrapped class from a ValueState (and therefore subjected to savepoint).
threadName (7eedaf4db54f14ae5b70ce55bfe409f0) switched from INITIALIZING to FAILED with failure cause: java.lang.Exception: Exception while creating StreamOperatorStateContext.

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:255)

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:268)

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:106)

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:700)

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:55)

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:676)

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:643)

    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:953)

    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:922)

    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:746)

    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:568)

    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not restore keyed state backend for KeyedProcessOperator_5856e2d12487eeccb905e376fa806891_(10/32) from any of the 1 provided restore options.

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:160)

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.keyedStatedBackend(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:346)

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:164)

    ... 11 more

Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.state.BackendBuildingException: Caught unexpected exception.

    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackendBuilder.build(RocksDBKeyedStateBackendBuilder.java:395)

    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend.createKeyedStateBackend(EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend.java:484)

    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend.createKeyedStateBackend(EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend.java:97)

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.lambda$keyedStatedBackend$1(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:329)

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.attemptCreateAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:168)

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:135)

    ... 13 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not find class 'old.class.path' in classpath.

    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.resolveClassByName(InstantiationUtil.java:775)

    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.resolveClassByName(InstantiationUtil.java:750)

    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializerSnapshotData.readTypeClass(KryoSerializerSnapshotData.java:186)

    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializerSnapshotData.createFrom(KryoSerializerSnapshotData.java:69)

    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializerSnapshot.readSnapshot(KryoSerializerSnapshot.java:81)

    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshot.readVersionedSnapshot(TypeSerializerSnapshot.java:175)

    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.NestedSerializersSnapshotDelegate.readNestedSerializerSnapshots(NestedSerializersSnapshotDelegate.java:178)

    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.CompositeTypeSerializerSnapshot.readSnapshot(CompositeTypeSerializerSnapshot.java:171)

    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshot.readVersionedSnapshot(TypeSerializerSnapshot.java:175)

    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil$TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationProxy.deserializeV2(TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil.java:174)

    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil$TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationProxy.read(TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil.java:145)

    at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil.readSerializerSnapshot(TypeSerializerSnapshotSerializationUtil.java:77)

    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.metainfo.StateMetaInfoSnapshotReadersWriters$CurrentReaderImpl.readStateMetaInfoSnapshot(StateMetaInfoSnapshotReadersWriters.java:237)

    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.KeyedBackendSerializationProxy.read(KeyedBackendSerializationProxy.java:184)

    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.restore.FullSnapshotRestoreOperation.readMetaData(FullSnapshotRestoreOperation.java:194)

    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.restore.FullSnapshotRestoreOperation.restoreKeyGroupsInStateHandle(FullSnapshotRestoreOperation.java:171)

    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.restore.FullSnapshotRestoreOperation.access$100(FullSnapshotRestoreOperation.java:113)

    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.restore.FullSnapshotRestoreOperation$1.next(FullSnapshotRestoreOperation.java:158)

    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.restore.FullSnapshotRestoreOperation$1.next(FullSnapshotRestoreOperation.java:140)

    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.restore.RocksDBFullRestoreOperation.restore(RocksDBFullRestoreOperation.java:102)

    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackendBuilder.build(RocksDBKeyedStateBackendBuilder.java:315)

    ... 18 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: old.class.path

    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)

    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)

    at org.apache.flink.util.FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.loadClassWithoutExceptionHandling(FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.java:68)

    at org.apache.flink.util.ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClassWithoutExceptionHandling(ChildFirstClassLoader.java:74)

    at org.apache.flink.util.FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.loadClass(FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.java:52)

    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)

    at org.apache.flink.runtime.execution.librarycache.FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders$SafetyNetWrapperClassLoader.loadClass(FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders.java:177)

    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)

    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.resolveClassByName(InstantiationUtil.java:773)

    ... 38 more

I did a class shift of the type 'old.class.path.MyClass' to 'new.class.path.MyClass'.
In another Class I have:
import new.class.path.MyClass;
//import old.new.class.path.MyClass; // old class path

import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.StateTtlConfig;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ValueState;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.ValueStateDescriptor;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.KeyedProcessFunction;

public class Operator extends KeyedProcessFunction<String, OperatorInput, OperatorOutput> {
    private ValueState<MyClass> myClassState;
    public void open(Configuration parameters) {
        ValueStateDescriptor<MyClass> myClassCacheDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("State", MyClass.class);
        myClassCacheDescriptor .enableTimeToLive(ttlConfig);
        this.myClassState= getRuntimeContext().getState(myClassCacheDescriptor);

    }
}

How can this migration be done while keeping the state submitted to Savepoint?
Edit I found this in the doc ☹️ :

Class name of the POJO type cannot change, including the namespace of the class.


I've seen a few approaches taken over the years but they generally fall into the following options:

Retain the Original Package Name - While this isn't fun or the best way to handle it, it's often the most simple. It depends on how you use your packaging (e.g. organization vs. functional) but it may be an option.
Consider Relocation via Shading - If you use something like the Maven Shade plug-in, it has support for class relocation which might be useful in this situation. Basically when your classes are built into your uber-jar, you could transform the namespaces to suit your old namespaces to ensure that despite the changes the code can still use them.
Write a Custom TypeSerializer - If you implement a custom TypeSerializer and associate it with your state descriptors, this should allow you to define the necessary logic for handling the migration from your old state to your new one which given just a package change may be trivial (obviously can vary depending on how complex your state is).
Reingest (if possible) - While this may not be applicable at all, depending on the state you are attempting to migrate, it can sometimes be possible to reingest the state in the new format.

